# KaTeX is not rendering

Tags: katex

I would really appreciate if someone could please take a look at my webpage and help me to figure out the reason why KaTeX does not render inline equations:

> https://vladivanov20.github.io/#!economics/cf.md

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the renderMathInElement functon that defines the delimeters. This is a minimal working example that I tested and works. Uses one of your equations.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.11.1/katex.min.css">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.11.1/katex.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.11.1/contrib/auto-render.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function ready() {
            renderMathInElement(document.body, {
                delimiters: [
                    { left: "$", right: "$", display: true }
                ]
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="ready()">
    <div class="md-text">$V = C_0 + \frac{C_1}{1 + r_1} + \frac{C_2}{(1 + r_2)^2} + \frac{C_3}{(1 + r_3)^3} + ...$</div>
</body>

</html>
```

And the result

[image: Katex]

Comment: Dear Hassan, thank you so much! I have been trying to fix this for hours and you really helped out. I appreciate it :)